# flutter/dart http package not redirecting to page

Tags: flutter, dart, http

I'm using: Flutter with the dart [http](https://pub.dev/packages/http) package;

I'm trying to do a post request to a website with then redirects me to another page.

I tried to do a post request using the http package in flutter like this:

```
var response = await http.post(Uri.parse("LINK_TO_WEBSITE"), body: {"data","data"});
```

when i do `print(response.body)` It prints:

```
<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="/User/Welcome">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>
```

Also the status code is 302

I should have got the redirected websites body.

but if i try to do the same in python using requests library It work straight up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Dart http package does not support redirection for POST method. It supports redirections only for GET or HEAD. You can check if status code is 302, then you can try to make another request. New url should be provided in header.

You can also try to add following header to your request:

```
"Accept": "application/json"
```

Comment: yeah but how do I make the server know that its me again.

Comment: Is this endpoint related to some kind of user interaction? If user is authenticated you should keep authorization token in application and send it each time when you request server.